# Create a Symfony app : how to organize logic/bundle

Tags: symfony, symfony3.x, symfony-3.4

I'm beginning a new Symfony 3.4 application in order to create a document management platform for our small business. I think I know how to organize all my code within several custom bundle but I'd rather ask for advice here ;)

Below is the tree I had in my mind :

```
---- MyCompany
-------- app
-------- bin
-------- src
------------ Custom bundle with UI / design elements ( = all the main templates / layouts for the app : header, footer, sidebar etc...)
------------ Custom bundle for User management ( = user management controllers, entities profile view etc...)
------------ Custom bundle for Product management ( = products CRUD, controller, entities, product page views etc... )
------------ Custom bundle for miscellaneous operations / tools
-------- tests
-------- var
-------- vendor
-------- web
```

Is that a good way to start an application ? Is there another way to do it ?
Thanks !

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/best_practices/business-logic.html

Comment: if it is a small business, then I think you don't need separate bundles for that one bundle enough for you, just separate your controller.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is an other way. Personally I don't like to couple my application logic with my framework and even [Symfony Best pratices](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/creating-the-project.html#application-bundles) doesn't recommend to create multiple bundles for your application logic.

You could have just one bundle (AppBundle/ApiBundle) and organized differently your logic (in your bundle or in an other folder).

Comment: Change the link to 3.4 version: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/best_practices/creating-the-project.html